# Can we add buttons for input on a Splash screen?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jquery-ui, preloader

I have to work on an app where the user has to interact with the app fast ( its for an emergency)

Is there a way to implement a pair of buttons on a preloader screen / splash screen on a PWA ?

PS:- I am a beginner please excuse me if this is a dumb question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour and then please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add buttons to the splash screen.

You can customize it by selecting a background color or icon (through the `manifest.json` file). The splash screen disappears as soon as the PWA is loaded.

If you are interested in learning more about PWAs, I wrote [a series of articles](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da) about this topic.